# pg_basebackup: error: could not read COPY data: server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: database, postgresql, centos7

We are using postgresql 13.6 master-slave configuration. Whenever I executed pg_basebackup command to get the files master to start replication, connection drops. I' ve been searching this error but still no clue why this happens. And logs does not provide any clue.
Can somebody help on this?

Pg_basebackup command

`pg_basebackup -h MASTER_IP -U postgres --checkpoint=fast  -D /var/lib/pgsql/13/data/ -R`

**Error**

```
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
pg_basebackup: removing data directory /var/lib/pgsql/13/data
```

**Master Configuration pg_hba.conf**

```
local all all trust

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0           md5


host replication all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
host postgres all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
host replication all 0.0.0.0/0 trust


# replication privilege.
host  replication postgres SLAVE_IP/32 md5
host replication replication SLAVE_IP/32 md5
-bash-4.2$
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Yes I tried with port option it does not work.

```
pg_basebackup -h MASTER_IP -p 5432 -U postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/13/data/ -Fp -Xs -R --checkpoint=fast
```

This is the log from master. I dont see any OS logs in slave

```
STATEMENT:  BASE_BACKUP LABEL 'pg_basebackup base backup' PROGRESS  FAST NOWAIT    MANIFEST 'yes'
```

Command output on Slave

```
FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command error: could not read COPY data: server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.
```

Using tar option right now with pg_basebackup command.

```
pg_basebackup -h MASTER_IP -p 5432 -U postgres -Ft  --checkpoint=fast -z  --wal-method=none -D - > /var/lib/pgsql/13/data_1/backup.tar
```

with tar option command output

```
pg_basebackup: error: could not read COPY data: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

No files found owned by root under postgre directory

```
[root@master01 data]#  find /var/lib/pgsql/13/data/ -group root
[root@master01 data]#
```

Comment: 1) Have you looked at the OS system logs to see if it is on that end? 2) You are not specifying `--port` so are you sure you are connecting to correct Postgres instance? **ADD answers** as update to question.

Comment: you can check it...

Comment: 1) Why are you taking a `pg_basebackup` if you already have replication set up and running? 2) What happens if you shut down the replication before taking the backup?-

Comment: 1) We had Master slave replication in old servers. I had to migrate the postgres to the new ones(servers). Before the migration I tested I took the backup of the master(pg_dump) and restore to the new machine and configured replication it was working. After the real migration completed I couldnt start the replication due errors above.
2)Right now there is no replication between new servers.  Replication is already closed.
I am creating tar file with using pg_basebackup command. Updating question.

Comment: I will run pg_basebackup locally then untar in secondary